# SSIS: dynamic source file connection

Tags: ssis

I am working in BIDS (SSIS 2008).  I have a flat file connection to a pip-delimited file with a .pip extension.  The file name can change significantly.  However, it will always have the word 'stuff' in the file name.  For example, a valid file name is 123_x_stuff_456.pip.  How can I set up a dynamic connection for this dynamic file name?

So far, I have created a variable to hold the UNC path of the file (e.g., \drive1\folder1).  My next step (I think) is to create an expression in the flat file connection manager to concatenate the file name to the UNC path variable.  The problem I am running into is that I can't specify wildcards for the text before and after the token that I'm search for in the filename.  For example, in SSMS, I would concatenate the UNC path variable to something like '%stuff%.  For all tutorials that I've seen on this, they always follow a prescribed file name format, whereas, in my situation, the format will always be different (other than the token that it will always contain).  How do I go about this?

Comment: Either use a script task or possibly a for each loop (which can handle wildcards but will loop over all the matches)

Comment: There are many examples of using a for each loop to do this: http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Looping-over-files-with-the-Foreach-Loop.aspx. The general idea is you use a wildcard to populate a recordset with multiple file names (or in your case possibly only one), then you process each file individually. In other words, to turn your wildcard into a real file name, use a for each file loop.